# How do I move an existing display object behind another in Corona Lua?

Tags: lua, corona-sdk

If I have two existing display objects in Corona, lets say `do1` and `do2`. Assume `do1` is drawn first then `do2`, so `do2` will be on top.

Is there a way to say "put `do2` behind `do1`" in corona Lua? If yes can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `do1` and `do2` are in a [display group](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/group-display-objects) they appear in the order you insert them as:

```
local group = display.newGroup()
group:insert(do1)
group:insert(do2)
```

Groups are also numerically indexed and the objects are in display order based on the index:

```
assert(group[1] == do1) -- do1 is on the bottom
assert(group[2] == do2) -- do2 is on the top (front)
```

If you happen to add your items out of order, you can move another item to the top in a number of ways:

```
local group = display.newGroup()
group:insert(do2) -- do2 is on the bottom
group:insert(do1) -- do1 is on the top (front)

-- Move do2 to front by re-inserting it - only one instance will exist in group
group:insert(do2)

assert(group[1] == do1) -- do1 is on the bottom
assert(group[2] == do2) -- do2 is on the top (front)

-- Move do2 to the front

do2:toFront()

assert(group[1] == do1) -- do1 is on the bottom
assert(group[2] == do2) -- do2 is on the top (front)

-- Move do2 to the back

do2:toBack()

assert(group[1] == do2) -- do2 is on the bottom
assert(group[2] == do1) -- do1 is on the top (front)
```

See also [toFront()](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objecttofront) and [toBack()](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objecttoback).

You an only put items in the front or back. As far as I know there's no way to arbitrarily place items. You can however maintain display order in another list and insert them based on that order.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need organization and don't need to change the display order later on, you can just do:

```
do2:toBack()
```

Or:

```
do1:toFront()
```

Now, if you want to maintain them later on, then put both do1 and do2 into a display group:

```
doGroup = display.newGroup()
doGroup:insert(do2)
doGroup:insert(do1)
```

The fact that do1 was inserted last means it will now appear at the top. Also, a display object such as do1 or do2 can only be in **one** display group at any time, so you have effectively taken them away from the default display "stage" (which all display objects are placed by default) and moved them to a new one (the doGroup), which is now in another order.

Answer (score 0):

Just Googled this question and since it's still unanswered, here's the way to do it for others in need:

```
local group = display.newGroup()
group:insert(do1)

for n = 1, group.numChildren do
    if group[n] == do1 then
        group:insert(n, do2) -- this puts do2 behind do1
        break
    end
end
```