# How do I draw a border around a display object in Corona Lua?

Tags: lua, corona-sdk

What would be the easiest way to draw a thin border around a rectangle image display object in Corona Lua?

This is what I tried:

- Reviewed API and could not find a "border" method/property on displayObject
- Have tried creating a black box slightly bigger behind object, however can not see how to place object behind an existing object hence question [How do I move an existing display object behind another in Corona Lua?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27453/how-do-i-move-an-existing-display-object-behind-another-in-corona-lua)
- Google results for putting a border around a display object in corona didn't help

Comment: -1 this question shows no research effort. You should tell us what you've tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: @Byte56 - added to main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have display option available now. You can set strokeWidth & setStrokeColor based on your requirement for display objects.

Here is the help [link](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/display-objects)

Kudos!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can add an object behind another. Just add the black object (the border) first and then your main object. If you are using physics you have to set some flags so the 2 objects don't collide.  Why don't you just add a sprite for your object (png, jpg) ?

Comment: was really more from trying to understand what is possible in Lua/Corona - so I guess there's no API/SDK method then to do this...